# How to set @Environment(\.colorScheme) back to system/automatic?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

I'm trying to add a view in my app settings page where the users can choose to force dark mode, light mode or keep the system behavior.

If I add `.environment(\.colorScheme)` to the `ContentView` it works fine in case I force one of the two themes, but since the available options are only `.light` or `.dark` how do I get back to `.automatic`?

I also tried using a conditional modifier for the color scheme, which works, but the problem is that it ends up reloading the all app and it causes the app to jump form settings to the home screen.

Answer (score 5):

You can use preferred color scheme, like in below example

```
VStack {
   // ... some other code
}
.preferredColorScheme(someStateFlag ? .dark : nil)   // on some condition reset
```

Comment: I also tried with this but it does the same, light and dark works but setting nil doesn't change the theme back to what is set on the device

Comment: @LualdiDylan Yeah, this _does_ look like a SwiftUI bug. Someone posted a workaround on the Apple dev forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658818

Comment: As of today, setting `.preferredColorScheme(nil)` works fine on a real device and the simulator on x86 Mac with iOS 14.5. It seems to be bugged on the simulators on an M1 Mac with iOS 14.4, even a fresh simulator. Maybe I just need to upgrade there.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works fine

```
YourView
  .preferredColorScheme(
     AppEnvironment.environment == .develop ? ColorScheme(.unspecified) : .light
  )
```

Note:
You can add any condition instead of `AppEnvironment.environment == .develop`